# NSDictionary is not taking repeated characters

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a array with objects A,B,A,A,B with keys 1,2,3,4,5

but as A is repeated NSDictionary is not taking 'A' 2 times and gives error saying

```
-[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (1) differs from count of keys (0)'
```

So whats the solution for this

My Code:

```
Ar=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:A,A,A,A,A,nil];
Ar2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:1,2,3,4,5,nil];
    dic2=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:Ar forKeys:Ar2];
```

Comment: post your code for where you're setting objects for keys..

Comment: obviously you missed an object or a key.

Comment: code plz...what have you tried so far

Comment: The error is obvious, you are adding more objects than keys. I'm sure it's a syntax problem, if you post your code that'd help

Comment: Your keys are invalid. Either make them @"1", @"2" (i.e. strings) or make them objects [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]

Comment: Your two array init statements will not compile.  Maybe you should post the real code.

Comment: real array i am getting dynamically

Answer (score 1):

please try below code snip

```
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [data setValue:@"A" forKey:@"1"];
 [data setValue:@"B" forKey:@"2"];
 [data setValue:@"A" forKey:@"3"];
 [data setValue:@"A" forKey:@"4"];
 [data setValue:@"B" forKey:@"5"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using new syntax makes code more readable and could avoid such problems in most cases

```
NSDictionary *data = @{@"1" : @"A", @"2" : @"B", @"3" : @"A", @"4" : @"A", @"5" : @"B"};
```

Comment: Using even the old initWithObjectsAndKeys would help.

Comment: The readability is not improved at all. Old explicit syntax is only longer, not less readable.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this.

```
    NSArray *Ar=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A",@"A",@"A",@"A",@"A",nil];
NSArray *Ar2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,nil];
NSMutableDictionary *dic2=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:Ar forKeys:Ar2];
```

Best Regards.